# How to make class methods dynamically using instance variable value

Tags: ruby

Let see the code first that will help what I want to achieve:

```
class PostalInfo
  attr_reader :name, :code

  def initialize (id, name, code)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @code = code
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
    if method.to_s == "#{name}"
      return code
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

pi1 = PostalInfo.new(1, 'united_states', 'US')
pi2 = PostalInfo.new(2, 'united_kingdom', 'UK')
```

So when I run below code, it gives output as:

```
pi1.united_states => 'US'
pi2.united_kingdom => 'UK'
```

its fine upto here, but I also want to do something like

```
PostalInfo.united_states => 'US'
PostalInfo.united_kingdom => 'UK'
```

how to do that, thanks in advance

Comment: look up class methods in ruby

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic with `method_missing`? Why don't you create all methods when you load the class for the first time? Where are the keys and values coming from?

Comment: @spickermann do you mean I write some `method` which gets called when initialised. Yes it can be done like that. But that `method` what will be the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets up a class attribute to hold the data, and whenever an instance is initialized, it adds to that data structure, and uses a similar class-level `method_missing`.

```
class PostalInfo
  attr_reader :name, :code
  @@postal_info = {}

  def self.method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
    name = method.to_s
    if @@postal_info[name]
      @@postal_info[name]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def initialize (id, name, code)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @code = code
    @@postal_info[@name] = @code
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
    if method.to_s == "#{name}"
      return code
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
pi1 = PostalInfo.new(1, 'united_states', 'US')
pi2 = PostalInfo.new(2, 'united_kingdom', 'UK')
PostalInfo.united_states #=> 'US'
PostalInfo.united_kingdom #=> 'UK'
```

I will say, this seems like a weird design, and I'd normally recommend avoiding using mutable state with class methods, and `method_missing` wherever possible.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Is it possible to assign class attributes using some other way like using `class_eval` or `instance_eval` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
class PostalInfo
  POSTAL_HASH = {
    united_states: 'US',
    united_kingdom: 'UK',
  }.freeze

  def self.method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
    POSTAL_HASH[method] || super
  end
end
```

Skipping missing method might result in better performance:

```
class PostalInfo
  POSTAL_HASH = {
    united_states: 'US',
    united_kingdom: 'UK',
  }.freeze

  class << self
    POSTAL_HASH.each do |name, code|
      define_method(name) do
        code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It will work when you know the POSTAL_HASH well in advance, but I'm looking for dynamic hash, say if I run `PostalInfo.france` it will also add this info

Answer (score 0):

With one exception, you need to mimic the code in the first part of your answer in the class' singleton class. The difference concerns the initialisation of the instance variables. Rather than using `PostalInfo::new` and `PostalInfo#initialize`, you need to create a class method for doing that (which I've called `add_country_data`). Note that as the class' instance variable `id` is not used I've not included it in the code.

```
class PostalInfo
  class << self
    attr_reader :country_data

    def add_country_data(name, code)
      (@country_data ||= {})[name] = code
    end

    def add_country_data(name, code)
      @country_data[name] = code
    end

    def method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
      return country_data[method.to_s] if country_data.key?(method.to_s)
      super
    end
  end
end

PostalInfo.add_country_data('united_states', 'US')
PostalInfo.add_country_data('united_kingdom', 'UK')
PostalInfo.united_states
  #=> "US" 
PostalInfo.united_kingdom
  #=> "UK" 
PostalInfo.france
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `france' for PostalInfo:Class)
```

Though this meets your requirement, I would be inclined to construct the class in a more conventional way:

```
class PostalInfo
  attr_reader :name, :code
  @instances = []

  def initialize(name, code)
    @name = name
    @code = code
    self.class.instances << self
  end

  singleton_class.public_send(:attr_reader, :instances)
end

us = PostalInfo.new('united_states', 'US')
uk = PostalInfo.new('united_kingdom', 'UK')
us.code
  #=> "US" 
uk.code
  #=> "UK"
PostalInfo.instances
  #=> [#<PostalInfo:0x00005c1f24c5ccf0 @name="united_states", @code="US">,
  #    #<PostalInfo:0x00005c1f24c71858 @name="united_kingdom", @code="UK">]
```

Comment: thank you for the efforts, the first answer though fulfill the desired output. But I'm actually looking for is: class `PostalInfo` need to have all methods whose names are all its instances's `name` attribute/property values that will return corresponding `code` values
eg. `pi3 = PostalInfo.new(3, 'france', 'FR')`, then method `PostalInfo.france` will be available